# traceroute is not showing ip's instead it showing stars

Tags: networking, ip, traceroute

I have installed **traceroute** in my ubuntu 18.04. Now when I want to trace a website's ip route then in the first line it shows a ip (may be my ip address) but in the fext following address it prints only stars instead of ip address. But it works fine on windows pc.

In my ubuntu 18.04LTS

```
mefahimrahman@Night-Fury-P452LA:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.160.142), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  3.510 ms  5.013 ms  4.967 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

But in windows pc it gives:

```
C:\Users\Aurangzeb>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [172.217.26.206]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     6 ms     2 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     5 ms     2 ms     3 ms  172.18.1.10
  3     7 ms     8 ms     3 ms  gw-agg1-ssali-71-65.ssalibd.net [103.80.71.65]
  4   182 ms   182 ms   182 ms  43.224.113.25
  5   190 ms   188 ms   183 ms  43.228.208.21
  6   203 ms   191 ms   186 ms  43.228.208.5
  7    63 ms     *      100 ms  103.15.40.158
  8    63 ms    69 ms    62 ms  103.15.41.146
  9    75 ms    67 ms     *     74.125.242.35
 10    62 ms    62 ms    62 ms  216.239.35.168
 11    94 ms    72 ms    84 ms  209.85.242.158
 12    79 ms    86 ms    70 ms  108.170.253.97
 13    75 ms   103 ms    73 ms  74.125.253.69
 14    76 ms   100 ms    69 ms  maa03s23-in-f206.1e100.net [172.217.26.206]

Trace complete.
```

How can I get expected result in my ubuntu OS?

Comment: I suspect it's because `traceroute` is using UDP probe packets by default - and your firewall settings are blocking them. IIRC Windows `tracert` uses ICMP - so you could try `traceroute -I` or `traceroute --icmp` (but it requires elevated privileges i.e. may need to be run using `sudo`)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you it works fine for  **sudo traceroute -I** but **sudo traceroute --icmp** is not working.

Comment: That's odd - `-I` and `--icmp` should be the exact same options. What is your traceroute version (`traceroute --version`)?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning most modern Ubuntu systems use `traceroute6` or `tracepath` which are technically different than `traceroute` - although I agree with @steeldriver the `-I` and `--icmp` should be the same.

Comment: Yeah, finally it works!! After restarting my pc both commands are working fine. Thank you  @steeldriver

Comment: @steeldriver Add your comment as an answer.